# How to Access Transaction Array Value from IPN

Tags: php, arrays, paypal

I am trying to parse an IPN callback from paypal. The type of payment is adaptive, so there is an array of transactions (even though I will only have 1).

Here is a sample IPN with some fields pruned for readability:

```
 array (
'payment_request_date' => 'Fri Jan 30 22:28:54 PST 2015',
'verify_sign' => 'removed',
'transaction[0].id_for_sender_txn' => 'removed',
'transaction[0].receiver' => 'removed',
'cancel_url' => '#pruned',
'transaction[0].is_primary_receiver' => 'false',
'pay_key' => '#removed',
'action_type' => 'PAY',
'transaction[0].id' => 'id is here',
'transaction[0].status' => 'Completed',
'transaction[0].paymentType' => 'SERVICE',

 )
```

I am trying to access the value of 'transaction[0].id' and cannot get it to dump. I have tried basically every possible way I can think of:

```
 $id = $_POST['transaction'][0]['id']; 
 $id = $_POST['transaction[0].id'];
```

Also tried asking the array to a var and then using that:

```
 $id = $array->transaction[0].id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This should give you the info you need](http://enjoysmile.com/blog/24/paypal-adaptive-payments-and-ipn-part-two/).